# Node.js generated JWT secret, nanoid() vs crypto.randomBytes() which is stronger

Tags: hmac, jwt

Which method will generate stronger secret?

64 character secret generated by nanoid (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) with characters: 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-
e.g.: hNr3COb9fSz5qfZBCQx3GkpLVW-tbVM0E-Nl8xgcf8Js8-l6fqOIfSd6Gk-T_nkE

or
crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex')
e.g.: d152189824ea6b25c34048960dfa57722d547eff9e4e98a67064d910010e6747

both create 64 character number but I'm not sure which is stronger as a secret for JWT signing (HS256)

Comment: Nanoid doesn't seem to be made for this - it generates an ID not a key. Just generating 32 secure random bytes is fine for HMAC/SHA-256 - presuming you are OK with keeping it in software of course, but that's generally OK for tokens. Don't confuse hex / base 64 with the bytes that are encoded using them.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes do I understand correctly that decoded secret from .randomBytes() has higher entropy than secret generated from 64 alphabet characters? (e.g. decoded secret: �txK�:O�>�o/2�L�Q�B� has characters like ">" "/" and some that aren't represented in utf-8 e.g. �) so its harder to theoretically brute force it?

Comment: That depends what is encoded by those characters. Nanoid seems to encode 126 bits of random bits from the same crypto module. For HMAC/SHA-256 you'd normally use a 256 bit / 32 byte key, and larger key sizes are unnecessary. `crypto.randomBytes` should normally use the RNG of the OS which is fine. Not sure about the exact entropy in there, but on a correctly configured system I'd expect 128 bits *minimum*. Entropy is always a bit of a laden term when it comes to PRNG's and - sorry - JavaScript / NodeJS documentations is terrible so you'd have to look into the source code to be sure.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes got it, thanks a lot.